# http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs gives ","additionalProperties":{"type":"object"}}},"401":

Tags: spring-boot

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

```
//Bean - Docket

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);
}
```

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html works fine. Issue with http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

Comment: 2.0"}},"host":"localhost:8080","basePath":"/","tags":[{"name":"basic-error-controller","description":"Basic Error Controller"},{"name":"hello-world-controller","description":"Hello World Controller"},{"name":"user-resource","description":"User Resource"}],"paths":{"/error":{"get":{"tags":["basic-error-controller"],"summary":"error","operationId":"errorUsingGET","produces":["*/*"],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"object","additionalProperties":{"type":"object"}}},"401":{"description":"Unauthorized"},"403":

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in WebSecurityConfiguration

```
.antMatchers("/swagger**",  "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api**").permitAll() // permit all swagger url
```

If you wanted to add JWT authentication in Swagger add below in SpringFox

```
private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(
                "Title",
                "Description",
                "1.0",
                "Terms of service",
                new Contact("name", "URL", "name@email.com"),
                "License of API",
                "API license URL",
                Collections.emptyList());
    }
```